# How can I restore my backup files in Notepad++?

Tags: windows-10, backup, notepad++

My laptop's hard drive recently crapped out, and I had to reinstall everything. Before doing so, I made sure to back up all the Notepad++ backup files located in C:\Users[User]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup\ .

Now I've successfully reinstalled Notepad++ (the newest version, v7.4.2), and I've put the old backup files into the new backup folder, but when I open Notepad++, it fails to restore the old backup files.

I recognize that there are a lot of existing Superuser questions that are somewhat similar to my question. But I know exactly where the backup files are and where they belong, and I have both "Remember current session for next launch" and "Enable session snapshot and periodic backup" checked. My problem is that I can't get Notepad++ to restore the backup files that are in the backup folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

#### These backup files matter

**Your text documents**

1. Locate and open Notepad++ directory.*
2. Open `session.xml` file to see its content.
3. At each row starting with tag `<file` you can see `backupFilePath="somePath"` attribute. That `somePath` is backup path of that file, if there was a backup. Otherwise the value is empty.

**Your Notepad++ configuration**

In your N++ directory*, please focus on this subset of XML files:

```
config.xml         - general configuraion, mainly from Preferences dialog
contextMenu.xml    - customized context menu (right-click in text file)
nativeLang.xml     - Notepad++ UI translation currently in use
session.xml        - list of open files and some of their stuff (bookmarks etc.)
shortcuts.xml      - settings from Shortcut Mapper
stylers.xml        - settings from Style Configurator
userdefinelang.xml - user defined languages
```

By viewing these files you can easily learn what parts of configuration they contain and either restore everything or only required parts of configuration.

**If you have any problems restoring old XML files, just grab a merging tool (e.g. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)) and merge your settings from old XML files into XML files from current version.** It is manual work, but not so hard nor lengthy.

---

*) Based on your Notepad++ installation, this can be in your `%APPDATA%` directory, i.e. in different directory than the `Notepad++.exe` file is located. If you are not sure where it is, search your backup for `session.xml` file (or other XML files listed above).